# Typescript is not returning nested type while returning nested object

Tags: typescript

I want my function to return nested type of Content but it is not working even when we are sure about type that should be returned. Let's look at example:

```
type Content = {
    some: {
        extra: string;
        prop: number;
    },
    other: string,
    somenumber: number
}

const factory = (content: Content) => {
    return (key: keyof Content) => {
        return content[key];
    };
};

const content:Content = {
    some: {
        extra: "wow",
        prop: 123
    },
    other: "abc",
    somenumber: 999
};

const el = factory(content);
const some = el("some"); // good, I can pass only existing key as a string
console.log(some.extra); // error, can't reach "extra"
```

[LIVE EXAMPLE](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Content%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20some%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20extra%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20prop%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20other%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20somenumber%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20factory%20%3D%20(content%3A%20Content)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(key%3A%20keyof%20Content)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20content%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20content%3AContent%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20some%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20extra%3A%20%22wow%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20prop%3A%20123%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20other%3A%20%22abc%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20somenumber%3A%20999%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20el%20%3D%20factory(content)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20some%20%3D%20el(%22some%22)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(some.extra)%3B%20%2F%2F%20I%20expect%20%22some%22%20to%20contain%20%22extra%22%20and%20%22prop%22%20)

I expect "some" to contain and propose "extra" and "prop" but taking "extra" is throwing up TypeScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your function with a generic type parameter so Typescript can correctly infer the types:

```
const factory = (content: Content) => {
    return <K extends keyof Content>(key: K) => {
        return content[key];
    };
};
```

[See this live example.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Content%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20some%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20extra%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20prop%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20other%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20somenumber%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20factory%20%3D%20(content%3A%20Content)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20Content%3E(key%3A%20K)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20content%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20content%3AContent%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20some%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20extra%3A%20%22wow%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20prop%3A%20123%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20other%3A%20%22abc%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20somenumber%3A%20999%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20el%20%3D%20factory(content)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20some%20%3D%20el(%22some%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20good%2C%20I%20can%20pass%20only%20existing%20key%20as%20a%20string%0D%0Aconsole.log(some.extra)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%2C%20can't%20reach%20%22extra%22)

Answer (score 1):

The fix is pretty simple:

```
const factory = (content: Content) => {
    return <T extends keyof Content>(key: T) => {
        return content[key];
    };
};
```

The difference is that now we're limiting the type of `key` to passed string literal rather than any `Content` key